# How do I port forward on a Home Station Fibra òptica Amper EG-663 Amper router?

Tags: router, port-forwarding, port

[image: http://i.gyazo.com/86e63e79d11835ec9ab71e0b8680cc8d.png]

I cant find where port forwarding is in this one.

I know how to open ports on my other routers.

Model: Home Station Fibra òptica Amper EG-663 Amper

Comment: ok i will upload a better one

Comment: http://gyazo.com/07d9139c8e23e72a207b8e14e170aed4 
its amper i believe

Comment: Welcome to superuser. It would be helpful if you edited your post to include your router's model information _and_ assured the community that you've already Googled your router's model with the term _port forwarding_ (you have, correct?)

Comment: I did as i said i know how to open other ports,
I just dindt gave more information because im not sure which information i can give safetly (i will give the router model information one secc)

Comment: Model:Home Station Fibra òptica Amper EG-663
Amper

Comment: I posted a new link on the original post, from a guy that helped me, not from this webstie. may this help amper users in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Do you speak Spanish?. See [Port Forwarding no Vivo Fibra](http://forum.tecnologia.uol.com.br/port-forwarding-no-vivo-fibra_t_2338502) .

About 1/2 way down the page is the answer. You need to go to advanced settings, then policy routes...

[image]